# How can i change UI of my page after async call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asynchronous

I am having async call on my page, 
This takes about 1 minute.
I need to change UI after call completes.
Sample code is give below.

```
 protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    apicasystemWPMCheckStatsService.CheckStatsServiceClient obj = new apicasystemWPMCheckStatsService.CheckStatsServiceClient();
    string xmlOptionForGetCheckStats = "<options><mostrecent count='1'/><dataformat>xml</dataformat><timeformat>tz</timeformat></options>";
    string checkId = "";


    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "test" + "\r\n";
    obj.BeginGetCheckStats("admin@azuremonitoring", "Cu4snfPSGr8=", "PD6B685A0-006A-4405-951E-B24BB51E7966",
                                       checkId, xmlOptionForGetCheckStats, new AsyncCallback(ONEndGetCheckStats), null);


    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "testdone" + "\r\n";


}


public void ONEndGetCheckStats(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "testcomplete" + "\r\n";

}
```

The question is that how can i get "testcomplete" in my textbox. as my page is not getting posted back after this async call....

My current O/P :
test
testdone

Expected:
test
testdone
testcomplet

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can not do it like that. Because once the ASPX page is sent to the client there is no somple way for the server to communicate with that page.

You can do this however with AJAX. In your `Unnamed1_Click` set up a "flag" in `Session` that signals that an async operation is pending. In your `ONEndGetCheckStats` set that "flag" to signal that the operation has completed.
Add an ASP.NET page method ([Quick Tutorial](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)) to your code-behind that:

- Checks whether the operation is pending and returns `null` wehen it is
- When operation is finished removes everything from `Session` and returns the text that you need

On your ASPX page wire up a client-side event on the `Unamed1` (a poor name for a button btw) button that starts a client-side loop checking the status using that PageMethod. When status is not `null` anymore Javascript to change the `TextBox1` text.

Comment: Hey, Juhan, I know this things, btw this is just sample code so my button name is not proper, in WebMethod I am not able to access controls. and My page is having 3-4 usercontrols and access those and code is also quite complex so i need some other way.

Comment: The thing is that, COntrol is getting affected, like my Textbox is having Text property to "test testdone testcomplet" but the prob is that due to page is not refreshed test completed, never comes into textbox!!!!!   Did you get my point?